# Process Hung due to scheduler time-out in Multi-Core system

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, multicore

We have an ISR that can get executed on any of the available cores and may result success or failure condition based on whether the core is busy or free.In handler, we queue the work on work queues per core using queue_work_on() function.For each core, queue_work_on() function will be called and based on the return values of queue_work_on(), how can we pass the ISR return values IRQ_HANDLED, IRQ_NONE

How to handle when any one of queue_work_on function fails and how to return the ISR value.

Hope I provided enough context to get some view on it.

Edit:

Scenario is more like: 
we have e.g. 1024 queues which are consumed by multiple processes for performing some offload function by a host driver. After submitting for offload, a process gets blocked with wait_for_completion() call and ideally should get awaken by a completion notification. In driver offloaded rings are enqueued and based on offload success, an isr notifies worker threads to dequeue rings jobs and trigger a completion event.
Now we see more no of completion event than the waiting processes resulting in a process hung with TASK_UNITERRUPTIBLE state resulting in a scheduler timeout. Need some pointers to deploy possible synchronisation in a multi-core system

Answer (score 0):

When you get an interrupt request that actually comes from your device, you *must not* return `IRQ_NONE`. The consequence of that would be that the kernel thinks your device's interrupt line is stuck, and disables the device.

If you do not know on which CPU core to queue some work, use `queue_work()` to get the next free core.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I tried the suggestion but no difference :(
Scenario is more like: we have e.g. 1024 queue which are consumed by multiple processes for performing some offload function by a host driver.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I tried the suggestion but no difference :(
Please see edited query with more details on scenario and resulting issue.
Hope that will help you to give me more relevant pointers to explore further.